# In PHP, what is the best way to unsort a sorted array of objects when given the original order?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have one array of ID numbers in a desired particular order. I have a second array of objects that were sorted by an ID property from the first array.

```
$array1 = [3,4,2,1,5];

$array2 = [
    ["id" => 1, "data" => "one"],
    ["id" => 2, "data" => "two"],
    ["id" => 3, "data" => "fre"],
    ["id" => 4, "data" => "foe"],
    ["id" => 5, "data" => "fie"]
];
```

In PHP, what is the best way of 'unsorting' or reverting the second array to the original order of the first array?

The closest answer I can find without using a sort is:

```
$array1_flipped = array_flip($array1);

$array2_unsorted = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
  $array2_unsorted[$array1_flipped[$array2[$i]['id']]] = $array2[$i];
}

return($array2_unsorted);
```

**Edit**: For those interested, here is how the question arose. The first array is a list of IDs to be displayed in a particular order. The second array is the return of the MySQL call `WHERE id IN $array2`, which is returned sorted. However, the second array needs to be resorted back into the order of the first array. Due to size issues, I was hoping to be able to remap the second array using the keys and values of the first array *without* sorting.

Comment: Many things. I'm especially interested if I can do this by only using the first array, and then `array_multisort()`ing the second. I've tried to find an "inverse" of the first array to sort with, but to little avail, especially given that my ID numbers aren't sequential.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried and then we can help you from there...

Comment: Please note this site is not a code-writing service. Please post your existing code and we will attempt to fix it and explain the fix so you can improve in the future

Comment: I neither asked nor expected anyone to write code for me. The point was that there was no problem with my existing code; I was exploring a new idea and asking for advice regarding efficiently sorting arrays. I was especially interested if anyone knew how to apply a mathematical inverse map to array keys, but never mind. When in doubt, figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by introducing a third array and using a method similar to Gauss-Jordan elimination. While this is beautiful, I wish there was a one-step algorithm for this. I'll award the correct answer to anyone who finds it.

```
$array1 = [3,4,2,1,5];
$array2 = [
    ["id" => 1, "data" => "one"],
    ["id" => 2, "data" => "two"],
    ["id" => 3, "data" => "fre"],
    ["id" => 4, "data" => "foe"],
    ["id" => 5, "data" => "fie"]
];
// Placeholder sorted ascending array (e.g. $array3 = [1,2,3,4,5])
$array3 = range(1,count($array1));

array_multisort($array1, $array3);
// Now $array3 = [4,3,1,2,5], the inverse map of an $array1 sort

array_multisort($array3, $array2);

return $array2;
```

Answer (score 0):

`usort` with an anonymous function receiving the order array via the `use` keyword:

```
$order = [3,4,2,1,5];

$ar = [
    ["id" => 1, "data" => "one"],
    ["id" => 2, "data" => "two"],
    ["id" => 3, "data" => "fre"],
    ["id" => 4, "data" => "foe"],
    ["id" => 5, "data" => "fie"]
];

usort($ar, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $ai = array_search($a['id'], $order);
    $bi = array_search($b['id'], $order);
    if($ai == $bi) return 0;
    return ($ai < $bi) ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($ar);
```

Comment: Thank you for recommending `use`; that is good to know. I'm afraid that a sort will be too costly, so ideally I'm looking for an O(n) solution, but I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: @ChrisThorsvik I think you're limited to sorting due to the way your data array is structured.  Obviously, if it were indexed it by the ID and you could access the members directly using your ordered array.